# How to solve union de-duplication problem in SQL

Tags: sql, select, union

If I want to make a Union between two tables (basketbalplayers and footballplayers), to only select one time the students who play both sports. But the problem is footballplayers use helmets which is a column in footballplayers table but basketball players don't have helmets. What should I do?

Comment: Remove the `helmets` column from the tables before doing the `union`.

Comment: A [mcve] of your table structure and data would make it easier to help you.

Comment: If you want to select only players who are in both the footballplayers and the basketballplayers tables, you want to do a JOIN, not a UNION.

Comment: Select NULL for helmets?

Comment: Is there a studentID or similiar field that is common to both tables?

Comment: Thanks, JJWillMC. A common field is clearly required for a JOIN. Should have included that bit in my comment.

Comment: You don't need `union` but an `intersect` of the common columns in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to query all the columns - query just the once you need (read: the columns commons to both tables):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM   footballplayers
UNION
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM   basketballplayers
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just bring back all first name & last name combinations from both tables? This does not bring back only students who apply to both tables and you will see duplicates with a UNION ALL

Comment: Should be `INTERSECT` instead of `UNION ALL`

Comment: Got caught up in my own head - it should be `union`, not `union all`, of course.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

I think you said you only want players who play both sports:

```
select first_name, last_name 
 from footballplayers f
 inner join basketballplayers b on f.first_name = b.firstname and f.last_name = b.last_name
```